# FAQ section for program execution problems

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, new-users

A lot of times, in the questions that I browse on Stack Overflow, new users complain about execution problems with their programs, being it errors, or exceptions. Yet, rarely they provide the error messages, unless asked for them. Their programs *"just go wrong"*, or *"don't work"*.

I usually answer only to Java-related questions, and I see this is a common new user behaviour. Their programs throw exceptions, yet they rarely post the stack traces, unless asked for them. Sometimes, they don't even mention the type of the exception being raised.

I'm assuming here that this behaviour is common with other questions, related to other programming languages, although I may be wrong.

So, in short, should there be a section in the FAQ, or some helping message while writing the question, encouraging users to post error codes, error messages, stack traces, etc., if their question is related to errors encountered?

---

Example from the Stack Overflow FAQ:

> **How do I ask questions here?**
>
> (...)
>
> Providing clarification promptly will help get you the best answers.

Right after could be added, for instance:

> E.g.: If you encountered an error with your program, including any error code, or error messages, will help other users identify the problem, and provide better answers sooner.